# Error message has been always showing. How to handle this error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, ng-messages

Once I fill the data in this field it needs to go off. But it didn't.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
   <label>Budget</label>
   <input name="budget" ng-model="newTrip.budget" required>
   <div ng-messages="newForm.budget.$error" ng-show="newForm.budget.$touched" role="alert">
       <div ng-message="required">
           <span>Number is required</span>
       </div>
   </div>
</md-input-container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing it slightly:

```
<div ng-messages="newForm.budget.$error"
  ng-if="newForm.budget.$invalid && newForm.budget.$touched"
  ...>
</div>
```

I shortened it slightly, but try adding in the ng-if and see if it shows/hides your error.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response bro!!
`ng-if="newForm.budget.$invalid && newForm.budget.$touched"` did the trick. $invalid only means it will show the error on the initial of the page too. You saved my day.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: @KumarImmanuel, If you found the solution helpful and solved your problem please accept it.